# TXD0/RXD0 to D+/D-

Tags: gpio, usb, serial, serial-console

I am working on a project involving serial communication with the Raspberry Pi (for which I was using a USB to serial cable). I'm currently building the final version of the hardware, and I'm soldering my own usb connector. I need to know which USB pins correspond to the GPIO pins on the Pi.

The two digital communication pins for USB are labled D+ and D-, how do these correspond to TXD0 and RXD0?

Comment: D+ and D- are differential signals and nothing to do with RXD/TXD.  Could you clarify what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

The traditional [UART/USART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) and the new [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) are worlds part.
Please read about the differences before wiring up two completely incompatible systems, possibly damaging the electronics and/or endangering yourself.
There are products that provide a USB to USART bridge such as [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) that handle the USB protocol, voltage levels etc and make the 2 ends compatible for communication.

[image: USB to serial]

Serial Communications can use several standards such as [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) and [RS485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) for long distance or TTL working 3.3v/5v for inter-chip communications possibly on the same PCB

To answer your question, if you use a bridge like the one I have mentioned, there will typically be 4 wires - Power At 5V, Tx, Rx and Ground. Tx wire should go to the [image: PI Pinout] board pin 10 (marked UART0_RXD) and the Rx wire should go to the board pin 8 (marked UART0_TXD). You should connect the ground wire to the Pi so that the reference voltages are the same. any pin marked Ground should do (6/9/14/20/25/30/39). You can ignore the power wire since the Pi is already powered separately (make sure to tape it off for safety if it does not have a insulated connector).

Notes
=> Make sure the adapter voltage levels for Tx / Rx are 3.3V and not 5V
=> you can use the above bridge as an additional serial port by hooking it up to a USB connector on the Pi and using the wires one the other device. You will need to figure out if the drivers are supported and the right serial port device (/dev/? ) to read/write

HTH